# SetWindowLongPtr doesnt work properly

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to subclass RichEdit in my program (here is c++ code: http://dumpz.org/46182/). _native_log is a hwnd of richedit. At first all works fine and LogWindow::wndProc callback called normal, but if i set some text in RichEdit or click on them LogWindow::wndProc stops work (there no any further calls of it). Is there any thoughts what's i do wrong?

```
void LogWindow::replaceNativeLog(HWND native_log_handle) {
    _native_log = native_log_handle;

    SendMessage(_native_log, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, (LPARAM) &_rich_edit_ole);
    _old_wnd_proc = (WNDPROC) SetWindowLongPtr(_native_log, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG) &wndProc);
}

LRESULT LogWindow::wndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (Msg) {
    case EM_STREAMIN:
        break;
    case WM_SETTEXT:
        break;
    };
    return CallWindowProc(_old_wnd_proc, _native_log, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Your question says SetWindowLongPtr, your code say SetWindowLong.  Not good.

Comment: Oh, it should be SetWindowLongPtr in code. I changed it in my sources, but forgot to change it on dumpz.org.

Comment: The cast should be to `LONG_PTR` not `LONG` and do you really have to use those C style casts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Common Controls version 6 the procedure of subclassing windows has been revised to eliminate the issues with previous versions. In particular it is no longer a problem if a control is subclassed more than once.

A comparison between subclassing pre-v6 Common Controls and the v6 way of doing things can be found at ["Subclassing Controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx). Instead of calling SetWindowLongPtr to replace the window procedure there is [SetWindowSubclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) which in addition to replacing the window procedure does all the internal bookkeeping. A consequence of the redesign is that you do not have to store a pointer to the previous window procedure either; if you need to call into the original window procedure there is [DefSubclassProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776403.aspx) at your disposal.

This of course will only help if all competing clients trying to subclass the a control all agree on using the v6 style subclassing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem. I actually develop a plugin for Miranda IM, and there was another function trying to subclass richedit i want. So there is a kind of conflict between my and that functions. Thanks all for trying to help.